# Performing different actions based on the list populating the recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

How do I populate my android recyclerview with different lists such that different actions are performed based on the list. For example,clicking on an item of list A would do something different from clicking on an item on list B.
Do I have to create separate adapters for each.

Comment: You can use different view type if you want to do using a single adapter.
Link - https://droidbyme.medium.com/android-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type-multiple-view-holder-af798458763b

Comment: @Siddarth - I'm not using multiple layouts on same recyclerview. It's a single layout but being populated with different lists at different times and which click actions will be different for the different lists

Answer (score 0):

You should have an interface which handle the different actions from the different lists:

```
public interface handleRecyclerViewClicksInterface {
    public void handleListAClick();
    public void handleListBClick();
    public void handleListCClick();
}
```

Then your adapter should looks like that:

```
package com.wimova.driver.service;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.wimova.driver.component.adapter.NewRidesAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private HandleRecyclerViewClicksInterface handleRecyclerViewClicksInterface;
    
    private List<String> myDataset = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyAdapter(HandleRecyclerViewClicksInterface handleRecyclerViewClicksInterface){
        this.handleRecyclerViewClicksInterface = handleRecyclerViewClicksInterface;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        switch (viewType) {
            case 2:
                return new MyViewHolder(parent, view -> handleRecyclerViewClicksInterface.handleBClick());
            case 3:
                return new MyViewHolder(parent, view -> handleRecyclerViewClicksInterface.handleCCLick());
            default:
                return new MyViewHolder(parent, view -> handleRecyclerViewClicksInterface.handleAClick()); // here we will treat the cases < 2 or > 3
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // handle on bind
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return myDataset.size();
    }

    protected static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, View.OnClickListener onClickListener) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // Return the correct item view type depending on the dataset (you need to implement your own logic)
        if(myDataset.get(position).equals("handleA")){
            return 1;
        }
        if(myDataset.get(position).equals("handleB")){
            return 2;
        }
        if(myDataset.get(position).equals("handleC")){
            return 3;
        }
        // it it match no case, return the default one
        return 1;
    }
}




class MainActivity extends Activity {
    
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    
    private MyAdapter adapter;
    
    private HandleRecyclerViewClicksInterface handleRecyclerViewClicksInterface;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.main_recyclerview);
        
        handleRecyclerViewClicksInterface = new HandleRecyclerViewClicksInterface() {
            @Override
            public void handleAClick() {
                // Example : Launch other activity
            }

            @Override
            public void handleBClick() {
                // Example : Send notification
            }

            @Override
            public void handleCCLick() {
               //  Example : Delete row
            }
        };
        adapter = new MyAdapter(handleRecyclerViewClicksInterface);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

better way is to create separate adapters (if list are not too many) put list inside framelayout in main file where you want to show list

```
<FrameLayout.....</FrameLayout>
```

then replace the frame on the basis of the list selected create different fragment for all list and handle them in that their respective fragment class